# Android GridLayout — deleting one layout weight causes all other cells to disappear

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I've created a simple GridLayout with a bunch of buttons. Every button has `layout_columnWeight` and `layout_rowWeight` set to "1" to cause the gridlayout to expand to fill the space.

[image: Simple GridLayout]

If I delete *any* of the weights, e.g. `layout_columnWeight` from the upper-left button, all of the *other* buttons in that column disappear.

[image: GridLayout with one weight removed]

Can anybody explain what's going on here?

My complete layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button24"
            android:text="7"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight=".01"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button25"
            android:text="8"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button26"
            android:text="9"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button28"
            android:text="4"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button29"
            android:text="5"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button30"
            android:text="6"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button34"
            android:text="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button35"
            android:text="2"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button36"
            android:text="3"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```